# Filter products on sale.order.line - Odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

I would like to filter `product_id` on `sale.order.line`.

Let me explain,

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string="Sale Order", )
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="Settlement", domain='')
```

On `sale.order`:

```
class SalesOrder(models.Model):
    _name = 'sale.order'
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    my_model_id = fields.One2many('my.model', 'order_id', string="My model")
```

I have a `tree view` for `MyModel` model on `SaleOrder` view, something like the tree view of `sale.order.line`, an additional line we could say.

But, on my model (MyModel), I would like to filter `product_id` by the items created on the current `sale.order`.

MyModel, serves to create a different product which is not on the `sale.order.line` already, and it has it's own treeview, like `sale.order.line` does.

I don't know if I'm explaining well,

I create a product from `MyModel` from a `sale.order` record, then I'm gonna add this recently created product to it's own tree view (which is not to say `sale.order.line` one), but I must browse the products (on `product_id`) created from the current `sale.order` only.

Any ideas?

Comment: You only need to filter product which created from sale.order?. Your requirements need some more clarification i think

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to filter

Comment: I am making more clarification here, if you Add/Create a product in sale.order.line , Example "AA" then only AA should be available in your MyModel tree view?

Comment: Yes! exactly, sorry it's a bit difficult to explain, but that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create many2many (to product.product) field insteds of creating one2many on Sales order I think then only using mana2many you can filter you sales order line products. This is just my thoughts based on your requirement.